# How can I insert "/km" text after the data given from v-model?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I use vuetify for text fields.
using v-model I display the text given from a object.

For example:
I have object named "distance" and the value of object is "50", in front-end I used v-model to display the data of "distance".

The problem: I want to have "/km" after the text/data display from the text field w/o affecting real data of "distance".

The display of text field is "50" I want to make it "50/km"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format it with computed, here is an example:

```html
<template>
  <input v-model="test" />
</template>

<script>
export default { 
  computed: {
    test() {
      return this.yourdata + '/km'
    }
  } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you give me an example how to do it using computed?

Comment: <input v-model="test"/>
    <script>
        export default{
            computed:{
                test(){
                    return this.yourdata + '/km'
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example, just put it in an html file and open it in any browser:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <title>Test-Vue</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <input v-model="distance">/km<br/>
    {{distanceWithKm}}
</div>
</body>

<script>
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            distance: '50'
        },
        computed: {
            distanceWithKm() {
                return this.distance + "/km"
            }
        }
    })
</script>
</html>
```